# Dúvida na conversão de Operador

Tags: c#, vb.net

tenho uma dúvida quanto a conversão de um operador em uma struct do c# para o VB.

C#

```
  public static Angle operator +(Angle a)
        {
            return a;
        }
```

vb

```
Public Shared Operator +(ByVal a As Angle)
        Return a
    End Operator
```

Gostaria de entender se essa diferença "public static Angle operator" para "Public Shared Operator" traz alguma diferença, porque o Angle no VB "some", ou o Byval a as Angle já reduz esse uso?

Comment: Isso é VB.NET e não VB6

Answer (score 0):

> Gostaria de entender se essa diferença "public static Angle operator" para "Public Shared Operator" traz alguma diferença, porque o Angle no VB "some", ou o Byval a as Angle já reduz esse uso?

Digamos que o `as Angle` já reduz esse uso. O nome disso é inferência. No VB não é obrigatório informar o tipo de retorno a menos que você tenha definido o parâmetro `Strict On`.

O código tem o mesmo efeito de:

```
    Public Shared Operator +(ByVal a As Angle) As Angle
        Return a
    End Operator
```